# wifi reconect /etc/pm/sleep.d/

Tags: networking, suspend, macbook-pro

I have now Installed ubuntu on my MacBook Pro.
Everything was working OOTB, except one thing, the wlan0 won't reconnect after the system was asleep.

the only solution to get reconnected since now was running these commands:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down ; sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

so i wrote a script called wifi.sh and placed it in /etc/pm/sleep.d/ which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
    resume|thaw)
sleep 0
    ifconfig wlan0 down
sleep 0.2
ifconfig wlan0 up
            ;;
esac
```

unfortunately, this script is not running after waking up, but if i run

```
sudo /etc/pm/sleep.d/wifi.sh resume
```

it works fine.

the permissions seems also to be fine as you can see here:

```
jason@jason-MacBookPro:~$ ls -l /etc/pm/sleep.d/
total 20
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  210 Apr  6 22:43 10_grub-common
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  660 Mär  5  2015 10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1260 Mai 23  2012 novatel_3g_suspend
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  138 Sep 16 22:58 wifi.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  138 Sep 16 12:42 wifi.sh~
```

any help would be appreciated.

thank you
Jason